# Qemu debugging suddenly produces huge number of random instructions

Tags: debugging, assembly, bootloader, qemu, x86-16

I'm trying to make a very simple boot program, but I'm having problems debugging it. I'm using QEMU and connecting with GDB like this:

```
(gdb) set architecture i8086
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
(gdb) break *0x7C00
(gdb) layout asm
(gdb) continue
```

...which works great, and I can get to the first few instructions of my code. However, as soon as I `si` or `ni` at one particular `int` instruction, this pattern appears in the GDB assembly view.

```
0x8669  add    %al,(%bx,%si)                                               │
0x866b  add    %al,(%bx,%si)                                               │
0x866d  add    %al,(%bx,%si)                                               │
<ad nauseam>
```

This doesn't appear to stop, or return to where I expect it to. Here's my assembly code:

### stage1.S

```
#include "stage1.h"

.text
.code16
.org STAGE1_START

.globl _start
_start:
    JMP     main
    NOP

write:
    LODSB
    OR      %al, %al
    JZ      write_exit

    MOV     $0xE, %ah
    MOV     $0x9, %bx
    INT     $0x10
    JMP     write   

    write_exit:
        RET

video_setup:
    MOV     $0x0, %ah
    MOV     $0x3, %al
    INT     $0x10 /* This causes the problem. */
    RET 

LoadMsg:    .asciz "Loading second stage..."
BootDrive:  .byte
main:
    MOV     %dl, STAGE1_ABS_POS(BootDrive)
    CALL        video_setup
    LEA     STAGE1_ABS_POS(LoadMsg), %si
    CALL        write
    HLT

/* Fill file to 512 bytes, regardless. */
.fill           STAGE1_BOOTLOADER_SIZE - (. - _start)

/* BIOS magic. */
.word           STAGE1_BOOTLOADER_SIG
```

### stage1.h

```
#ifndef STAGE_1_H
#define STAGE_1_H

#define STAGE1_START            0x0
#define STAGE1_BOOTLOADER_OFFSET    0x7C00
#define STAGE1_BOOTLOADER_SIG       0xAA55

#define STAGE1_BOOTLOADER_SIZE      0x1FE

#define STAGE1_ABS_POS(X) (X-_start+STAGE1_BOOTLOADER_OFFSET)

#endif
```

I know the code doesn't jump somewhere randomly in memory, as the program works as it should when I run it without debugging options in QEMU.

What am I doing wrong? Criticism of my code generally is also much appreciated.

Comment: `add %al,(%bx,%si)` is what happens when you disassemble zeroes.

Comment: @harold: yeah, I figured it was the (initialised) memory in QEMU. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Maybe an interrupt is triggered which causes execution to continue past the `HLT`?

Comment: @Michael: Possible, although I find it odd that it only happens in one place, and never when the code is run without remote debugging. How would I check for that problem?

Comment: @MichaelRawson: you could try changing it into something like `forever: hlt` / `jmp forever` and see if it still ends up executing random code.

Comment: @Michael: my apologies, upon inserting the `HLT` instruction before the `RET` instruction, it appears the `INT` instruction is *actually* the trigger for the jump. Don't know if I'm blind or just incompetent, sorry.

Comment: Are you sure GDB is disassembling at the right address? i.e. cs:ip under 16-bit segmentation?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: `eip` is set to the correct address as shown in the disassembly, `cs` to `0xC000`. That would seem to be correct?

Comment: In that case, `eip` does not point straight to the current instruction - it points to the *offset* in the current code segment. The actual address is `cs * 16 + eip`, so, in this case, it'd be `0xC8669`, not just `0x8669`.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: of course it is, thanks. So I guess that the code I see is something in QEMU's BIOS interrupt handling, that GDB doesn't understand or has been told to ignore. I found a workaround, anyway. Thanks!

Comment: 16-bit segmentation is a very old mechanism that doesn't get used 99% of the time, so it wouldn't make sense for GDB to try to use it.

Comment: Isn't it simply the interrupt handler setup by QEMU running? `ni` only skips `call`, not `int` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know precisely why, but it turns out that interrupts end up confusing the debugger or QEMU's debug mode (or I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what).

Anyway, to work around this, I simply place breakpoints at the next instruction I wish to debug, then `continue` before an interrupt instruction.

Thanks for the help, commenters. :-)

Comment: It might depend on what level of emulation QEMU is configured to use (i.e. full software emulation, or using hardware virtualization through KVM). I know I've run into debugging issues with this before, and building QEMU with pure SW emulation fixed it for me.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I don't actually know; Debian provides `qemu` and `qemu-kvm` packages, so I presumed SW emulation. I'll look into it, thanks.